# Play .mp3 with Craftyjs

Tags: javascript, sound, crafty

I want to play .mp3 sound files in a game I built with Crafty.js. Is this possible without converting the sound file?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the browser you're using (not all support mp3). I'd recomend using mp4 audio. This should soon be supported by all popular browsers out of the box (actually I think even the Firefox stable supports it by now; that would mean all of them).

Comment: I didn't notice that. I'll test the game in Google Chrome.